# WC()->cart->fee_total and WC()->cart->get_fee_total() show zero on checkout page while fee is added

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a checkout field editor module that can attach a fee to an option field so that when you select such an option field, it'll add a fee to your cart and update the checkout total.

We also have a custom payment gateway module that shows the customer how much to pay, and the code to calculate the total looks like this:

```
$total_cart = (float)is_object( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->cart_contents_total : '';

$total_shipping = (float)is_object( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->shipping_total : '';

$total_tax = (float)is_object( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->tax_total : '';

$total_shipping_tax = (float)is_object( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->shipping_tax_total : '';

$total_fees = (float)is_object( WC()->cart ) ? WC()->cart->fee_total : '';

$total_amount = $total_cart+$total_shipping+$total_tax+$total_shipping_tax+$total_fees;
```

While variable `$total_shipping` updates well whenever another shipping method is selected, variable `$total_fees` does not update to the correct value when a fee is added (remains zero) unless the browser is refreshed. We've also tried calculating it using the function `get_fee_total()` instead, but it's the same result.

We're calculating the total using such a redundant way as `WC()->cart->total` or `WC()->cart->get_total()` initially show the correct value but becomes zero after the user selects anything on the checkout form resulting in "an Ajax refresh" to the cart.

Comment: Your problem is due to WooCommerce fragments.
The fragments are being cached and not getting refreshed once the fee is added.
If you are using `AJAX` to call the fee change you can just trigger a forced fragment refresh by executing `jQuery( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragment_refresh' );`

Comment: Hi @H.Bloch thanks for your comment. So the added fee has a separate fragment in wc? Because delivery fee doesn't have an issue, the variable immediately gets the correct value when switching the delivery method. Also the cart total is nicely updated in the browser when the fee is added. It's only the variable itself that doesn't get updated for some reason.

Comment: It might be that only the fee part is not included in the wc fragments response, try to see what comes back from the wc_fragments using the browser devtools.
You also can see the cached value under the localStorage